# Let the currently-running Photoshop on MacOS execute a script, by terminal command

Tags: macos, adobe-photoshop

In Windows, users can let the current-running Photoshop execute a JSX script by the following command line, for example:

`C:\path-to-Photoshop\Photoshop.exe D:\path-to-script-file\MyJsx.jsx`

I would like to do the similar job in MacOS, I tried the following line in MacOS terminal:

`/Applications/Adobe\ Photoshop\ 2020/Adobe\ Photoshop\ 2020.app/Contents/MacOS/Adobe\ Photoshop\ 2020 /tmp/MyJsx.jsx`

But this always launches a new Photoshop instead of manipulating the currently-running Photoshop. How can I let the current-running Photoshop execute a JSX script from terminal?